# IE causing huge area of space when prepending div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a testing site so I can't supply too much code. This prepend() method works great in everything but IE and it does not work in ANY version of IE. No console errors. I get a huge area of unselectable white space where the small div should be.

I have a div up in the navigation that contains a searchbar. I selected this searchbar. And put it into the sidebar.

```
    $('#sidebar').prepend($('#header_rowSearch'));
```

Like I said it works in every browser but IE.

The div being selected has no styles added to it. The sidebar has these:

```
#sidebar {
padding: 20px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
width: 345px; 
background-color: #162732; 
float: right;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle that exhibits this behaviour

Comment: It would be helpful if you set up a JSFiddle with HTML/CSS/JS that isolates and replicates the problem so we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: QuestionReader - exception : "the small div" undeclared identifier.

Comment: "where the small div should be" - what is the small div and where should it be?  could you provide some html

Comment: presumably the 'small div' he's referring to is the `#header_rowSearch` element he wants to prepend to the sidebar.

Comment: Here is a js fiddle. Of course it works in here. I can't get it to work on my site. http://jsfiddle.net/thomasp423/4gxvD/

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue. It stemmed from information I didn't supply. The ID was actually within a table and the markup was

```
<td id="header_RowSearch"></td>
```

IE is the only browser that tries to read it properly when you insert a table row into an actual div. So obviously a random row within a div is going to break things. That being said this line of jQuery saved the day.

```
$('#sidebar').prepend($('#header_rowSearch'));
$('#header_rowSearch').wrap('<table></table>');
```